# Filter roll-off between filter types

Tags: filter

When I looked at different filter types I see a variety of filter styles mentioned such as Butterworth or Chebyshev with different advantages/disadvantages. For example steeper roll off vs ripple.

But then I also see the roll off of a first order low pass filter given as 20 dB/decade, and that this is the same for all first order filters.

So how is it possible for different filter styles to have a steeper roll off for the same number of order/poles?

Answer (score 2):

Two things that separate filters between themselves are *filter selectivity* and *shaping factor*.

Filter selectivity is defined as the negative of the derivative of the transfer function, evaluated at the corner frequency. For example consider two, relatively random 2nd order transfer functions (which may well be a Chebyshev one and a critically damped one):

$$\begin{align}
A(s)&=\dfrac{1}{s^2+s+1} \tag{1} \\
B(s)&=\dfrac{1}{s^2+2s+1} \tag{2} \\
F_s^{A}&=-\dfrac{\text{d}|A(j\omega)|}{\text{d}\omega}\Biggr|_{\omega=\omega_p}=\dfrac{j-2}{j^2}=1 \tag{3} \\
F_s^{B}&=-\dfrac{\text{d}|A(j\omega)|}{\text{d}\omega}\Biggr|_{\omega=\omega_p}=\dfrac{j2-2}{(j2)^2}=0.5 \tag{4} \\
\end{align}$$

A higher value signifies a better selectivity, resulting in a steeper roll-off after \$\omega_p\$ (here \$\omega_p=1\$):

[image: filter selectivity]

The shaping factor is defined as the ratio of the bandwidths at different attenuation levels:

$$\begin{align}
\omega_1=4,\;\omega_2=8 \\
S_{\omega_1,\omega_2}^A&=\dfrac{BW_{\omega_2}^B}{BW_{\omega_1}^B}=0.2445 \tag{5a} \\
S_{\omega_1,\omega_2}^B&=\dfrac{BW_{\omega_2}^B}{BW_{\omega_1}^B}=0.2615 \tag{5b} \\
\omega_1=10,\;\omega_2=100 \\
S_{\omega_1,\omega_2}^A&=\dfrac{BW_{\omega_2}^B}{BW_{\omega_1}^B}=0.00995 \tag{6a} \\
S_{\omega_1,\omega_2}^B&=\dfrac{BW_{\omega_2}^B}{BW_{\omega_1}^B}=0.01 \tag{6b}
\end{align}$$

The two shaping factors are the virtually the same, showing that if the orders are the same, and the transfer functions similar, their shaping factor is the same. But notice that the higher the frequencies relative to \$\omega_p\$, the closer the results are. That's because the filter selectivity influences these results due to the steeper roll-off. This shows that, for the same order, all *all-pole* filters are the same.

[edit] And, if you look at the values, they will tell you the slope of the attenuation: when \$\omega_1\$ and \$\omega_2\$ were an octave apart, the values revolved around \$0.25\$, which signify \$20\log_{10}(0.25)\approx -12\;\text{dB/oct}\$, and when they were a decade apart: \$20\log_{10}(0.01)=-40\;\text{dB/dec}\$. [/edit]

In this category, and in the order of the lowest to the highest filter selectivity: Gaussian, Bessel, transitional (Bessel <-> Butterworth), Butterworth, Legendre, Papoulis, Halpern, Chebyshev (or Chebyshev type I). There are others.

If there are zeroes in the transfer function, those filters are *pole-zero* filters, and their attenuation is greatly influenced by the zeroes. From this category, in the same lowest to highest filter selctivity: inverse Pascal, inverse Chebyshev (or Chebyshev type II), elliptic (or Cauer). For example, a same relatively random 2nd order notch lowpass (could be elliptic/Cauer):

$$\begin{align}
C(s)&=\dfrac{1}{100}\dfrac{s^2+100}{s^2+s+1} \tag{7} \\
F_s^{C}&=-\dfrac{\text{d}|C(j\omega)|}{\text{d}\omega}\Biggr|_{\omega=\omega_p}=1.01 \tag{8} \\
\omega_1=1,\;\omega_2=2 \\
S_{\omega_1,\omega_2}^C&=\dfrac{BW_{\omega_2}^C}{BW_{\omega_1}^C}=0.2689 \tag{9a} \\
\omega_1=2,\;\omega_2=4 \\
S_{\omega_1,\omega_2}^C&=\dfrac{BW_{\omega_2}^C}{BW_{\omega_1}^C}=0.2032 \tag{9b} \\
\omega_1=4,\;\omega_2=8 \\
S_{\omega_1,\omega_2}^C&=\dfrac{BW_{\omega_2}^C}{BW_{\omega_1}^C}=0.1048 \tag{9c}
\end{align}$$

This time, the zero influences the high frequency response: it creates a great attenuation over a short transition width, but the price to pay is the flat response at high frequencies (though attenuated). [edit] This is for even orders, where the number of poles equals the numbers of zeroes; for odd orders, there will be a 1st order slope. [/edit] The filter selectivity is almost the same as (1), but the shaping factor is much lower than any of the other all-pole examples. [edit] However, that happens only if it's calculated away from \$\omega_p\$ and \$\omega_z\$, since the presence of the zero creates an uneven roll-off (9a,b,c) [/edit]:

[image: pole-zero]

If the lowest zero is much higher than the highest pole (one or two decades apart), then the shaping factor is the same as an all-pole filter of the same order, but only for a small portion. In the graph above, you can see how the slopes are vitually the same for a short period after \$\omega_p\$.

Comment: I've corrected the numbers for the selectivities (the formula shows the absolute value, yet I got complex) and added a few more clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

> *So how is it possible for different filter styles to have a steeper
> roll off for the same number of order/poles?*

**Example** - Elliptic (or Cauer) filters use resonant "blocking" (or notching) to create rapid and very-steep characteristics above the normal cut-off frequency: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/elliptic-filters).

Note that C2 and L2 form a resonant "block" or notch. So do L4 and C4. Each is a parallel resonant filter that creates notches at roughly 20 MHz and 30 MHz in the spectrum above. So, once you start making complex filters that utilize both "notching" and "passing" stages you can create very steep roll-off characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Quote: *When I looked at different filter types I see a variety of filter styles mentioned such as Butterworth or Chebyshev with different advantages/disadvantages. For example steeper roll off vs ripple.*

We should clearly distunguish between (a) "filter types" (different circuits, structures, topologies) and (b) transfer functions (so called "approximations" to an ideal response) like Bessel, Butterworth, Chebyshev,...

More than that, the "roll-off" characteristics (for frequencies above the transition range between pass and stop region of the filter)  depends on the filter order only - and not on the selected approximation.
The difference between the variuous responses (Chebyshev,...) does exist in the passband and the transition region only (gain peaking, ripple,...).

However, as demonstrated in another answer (Andy aka), when the transfer functions allows a real zero (Chebyshev-inverse or Cauer approximation) the roll-off is much steeper than predicted by the filter order only.

Quote: *But then I also see the roll off of a first order low pass filter given as 20db/decade, and that this is the same for all first order filters.
So how is it possible for different filter styles to have a steeper roll off for the same number of order/poles?**

There is only one first-order response - independent on the filter circuit (L-R or R-C or active). Different transfer characteristics (Butterworth etc,...) do exist for higher order functions only (n=2 or greater).